# After fresh installing Win7, what is the first thing to do? Install drivers (Sony) or just install Windows Updates?

Tags: drivers, sony-vaio

I am about to replace my old dead HDD in my Sony Vaio (VPCSA35GG) laptop. After installing Windows 7 pro 64 using a retail disk, what is the first thing I should do? Install EACH OF THE drivers (in order) from the Sony Website?

[image: Sony Vaio Drivers]
[image: Sony Vaio Drivers]

Or just install Windows Updates?

Or maybe when I finish installing Win 7, I should just check for any missing drivers and install ONLY them? What if I miss something? Is there way to check for missing drivers other than by checking each functionality manually?

And does the Windows disk usually contain every driver mentioned in the pic below? If that is the case, then I should only go for driver updates?

I would be greatly thankful if someone can guide me on this. Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: Install drivers first, then the updates.

Comment: Should I install each and every driver manually? then go for driver updates.. then go for windows updates? Thanks :) @Rahul2001

Comment: Windows 7 only ships with some generic drivers, you're gonna have to download and install most from the website anyways... The website usually contains the latest versions. Install them, then start Windows update. :D

Comment: **As long as you are not missing network drivers and there is not internet connectivity there is not hard and fast rule.** Go as you like.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal rule here. Some computers will receive better drivers through Windows Update, some work better with manually installed ones.

That being said, you can safely let Windows Update install whatever it finds, then check which devices have missing drivers and download them from Sony. It works pretty well most of the time. Even if drivers provided by Sony could work slightly better, the difference is usually unnoticeable.

Some tips:

- Frequently updated drivers (eg. NVIDIA graphics) are usually provided in slightly older versions through Windows Update - so they may be missing latest tweaks, but may also be more stable
- Device manufacturers are often reluctant to update downloads section on their website, so oftentimes Windows Update offers newer drivers
- Windows Update sometimes installs drivers without extra bloatware/control panels that nobody uses, which is nice
- In rare cases older drivers may work better or be mor fit to your preferences, but that can be found only through experimentation